# How to auto connect wifi on beaglebone custom linux

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack

How to auto connect wifi on beaglebone custom linux??

this is my wpa_supplicant.conf file

```
network={
        ssid="name"
        psk="pass"
}
```

this is my interfaces file

```
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wireless_mode managed
    wireless_essid any
    wpa-driver wext
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question.

In your network interface file, you need to add auto wlan0 or your WLAN name.

example:

```
# /etc/network/interfaces

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wireless_mode managed
    wireless_essid any
    wpa-driver wext
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Comment: Hi LethalProgrammer . I read it, but now I'm not having free time , I will answer later. Thanks you